# gauge highcharts : Exterior circle color

Tags: highcharts, geometry, gauge

Is there a way change or get rid of the gray circle in a Gauge chart from HighCharts?

[Look this Gauge pls](http://jsfiddle.net/xMjqp/)

```
$(function () {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'gauge',
        backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)',
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        plotShadow: false
    },      
    title: {text: ''},      
    pane: {background: [{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}]},
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 200,
        lineColor: 'transparent',
        minorTickColor: '#FF0000',

        tickColor: '#FF0000',
        labels: {
            step: 2,
            rotation: 'auto'
        },
    },  
    series: [{
        name: 'Speed',
        data: [80]
    }]      
  });
});
```

I can't find any option to change to color of the gray circle or to choose no to plooted.

Any ideas please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pane.background.borderWidth` property: http://jsfiddle.net/xMjqp/2/

From docs: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#pane.background

Comment: D'oh!  Very nice, I'm going to delete my answer.